# how to setup irc domain on another server?

Tags: cross-domain

like i have the site on one server but irc (the site uses) should be hosted on another hosting provider. i have domain set up for the site. should get another one for the irc hosting and do cname to it? what should i do?

Comment: Please move to ServerFault (and maybe fix up the wording)

Answer (score 3):

An irc subdomain (irc.example.com) is common, but if you want a different domain, that is your choice.

You can't use "example.com" for both the web site and the ircd if you want them hosted on separate servers.